# How to get full data using aqueduct and socket?

Tags: socket.io, dart, flutter, aqueduct

My flutter app connects to a socket via https and I am using aqueduct to get secure data. the socket data is full length string such as;

2_7#a_b_c_d_e_f_g#h_i_j_k_l_m_n#

I convert the data to json and my json data looks like:
   "{data:2_7#a_b_c_d_e_f_g#h_i_j_k_l_m_n#}"

and sent to flutter app. the 2_7# means I have 2 rows and 7 column.
The original server socket data 152_7# which means I have 152 rows with 7 column.

when I try to get this data (152_7#) using socket in aqueduct I get only 12 rows or sometimes 25 rows.

If the server data short I get all of them, but can get big string data.

my question is how to get full data using aqueduct and socket?

```
import 'package:aqueduct/aqueduct.dart';
import 'package:ntmsapi/ntmsapi.dart';

Socket socket;
String _reply;
var _secureResponse;
var _errorData;

class NtmsApiController extends Controller {

  @override
  Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {
    try {
      String _xRequestValue = "";
      _reply = "";
      _errorData = "Server_Error";

      if (request.path.remainingPath != null) {
        _xRequestValue = request.path.remainingPath;

        // returns a string like 152 row with 11 column
        socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.xxx.xxx’, 8080); 
        socket.write('$_xRequestValue\r\n');

        socket.handleError((data) {
          _secureResponse = "$_errorData";
        });

        await for (var data in socket) {
            // _cant get all the data from reply, reply shows about 25 row data
          _reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
          _secureResponse = "$_reply";

          socket.close();
          socket.destroy();
        } 
      } else {
        _secureResponse = "$_errorData";
      }
    } catch (e) {
        _secureResponse = "$_errorData";
    }

    return new Response.ok("$_secureResponse")
      ..contentType = ContentType.json;
  }
}
```